# Javascript - How can I read column in json file and save it in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I made a json file and its contents are like these:

```
[{"pdis": "pdistance", "time": "time", "lon": "longitude", "tdis": "totaldistance", "secsp": "sectionspray", "lat": "latitude"}, {"pdis": "0.000555", "time": "10:01:43", "lon": "126.952741667", "tdis": "0.000555", "secsp": "3343.0", "lat": "37.4805016667"}, {"pdis": "0.027396", "time": "10:01:57", "lon": "126.952753333", "tdis": "0.027951", "secsp": "3320.0", "lat": "37.4807483333"},~~~,{"~~~~~"}]
```

I want to read and save them in javascript array as:

```
pdis       time        lon            tds        secsp     lat
0.000555   10:01:43    126.95274      0.000555   3343.0    37.4805
0.027396   10:01:57    126.95275      0.02795    3320.0    37.4807
```

How can I do that? 
Please advice me or recommend some sites or pages.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly matching code sample can be found here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

```
JSON.parse('{"p": 5}', function(k, v) {
  if (k === '') { return v; } // if topmost value, return it,
  return v * 2;               // else return v * 2.
});                           // { p: 10 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After parsing the JSON string, you could use the following for building an array with the wanted parts.

```js
var array = [{ "pdis": "pdistance", "time": "time", "lon": "longitude", "tdis": "totaldistance", "secsp": "sectionspray", "lat": "latitude" }, { "pdis": "0.000555", "time": "10:01:43", "lon": "126.952741667", "tdis": "0.000555", "secsp": "3343.0", "lat": "37.4805016667" }, { "pdis": "0.027396", "time": "10:01:57", "lon": "126.952753333", "tdis": "0.027951", "secsp": "3320.0", "lat": "37.4807483333" }],
    keys = Object.keys(array[0]),
    result = array.map(function (a) {
        return keys.map(function (k) {
            return a[k];
        });
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwrf5fL6/) , it downloads the file with content

```
pdis time lon tdis secsp lat
pdistance time longitude totaldistance sectionspray latitude 
0.000555 10:01:43 126.952741667 0.000555 3343.0 37.4805016667 
0.027396 10:01:57 126.952753333 0.027951 3320.0 37.4807483333
```

It generally takes a **json array** and converts into **table format** thn downloads it as a **file** .

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var jsonString = '[{ "pdis": "pdistance", "time": "time", "lon": "longitude", "tdis": "totaldistance", "secsp": "sectionspray", "lat": "latitude" }, { "pdis": "0.000555", "time": "10:01:43", "lon": "126.952741667", "tdis": "0.000555", "secsp": "3343.0", "lat": "37.4805016667" }, { "pdis": "0.027396", "time": "10:01:57", "lon": "126.952753333", "tdis": "0.027951", "secsp": "3320.0", "lat": "37.4807483333" }]';

var result = JSON.parse(jsonString).map(function(obj, index) {
  var arr = Object.keys(obj);
  if (index > 0) {
    arr = arr.map(function(key) {
      return obj[key];
    });
  }
  return arr;
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```